# How do I keep the sentence based on a value in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a text column I want to split based on one other column (filter). In the example below you will see one column that contains a short article, and one column that contains the filter value.

```
    filter       text   
0   blue|shirt   In the state of alabama it is 35 degrees. We advise a blue shirt. Don't do anything else. Just where a shirt.
1   green|shirt  In the Netherlands you don't use a shirt. It is cold. We use Green sweaters. We advise a blue shirt. 
2   Red|shirt    This news is not good. The colour red makes me angry.
```

For the **desired outcome** i'm looking for a way to get the column below.

```
    filter       Desired outcome   
0   blue|shirt   We advise a blue shirt. Just where a shirt.
1   green|shirt  In the Netherlands you don't use a shirt. We use Green sweaters. 
2   Red|shirt    The colour red makes me angry.
```

I tried a lot of different ways but i didn't succeed.
It would be also great if I also have the option to get one sentence before and one sentence after the filter value.

What is the best code to use for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe as constructor?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split`, `explode`, a bit of regex and `groupby`:

```
import re
df['s'] = df['text'].str.split('\. ')
df1 = df.explode('s').drop(columns = 'text')
matched = df1.apply(lambda r: re.search(r['filter'].lower(), r['s'].lower()) is not None, axis=1)
df1[matched].groupby('filter', sort = False).agg('. '.join).reset_index().rename(columns = {'s':'text'})
```

output

```
    filter       text
--  -----------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  blue|shirt   We advise a blue shirt. Just where a shirt.
 1  green|shirt  In the Netherlands you don't use a shirt. We use Green sweaters. We advise a blue shirt.
 2  Red|shirt    The colour red makes me angry.
```

To get one before and one after, after the `matched = ...` line add this, which adds one before and one after of each matched sentence

```
...
matched = matched | matched.groupby(level=0).shift(1) | matched.groupby(level=0).shift(-1)
...
```

this is not very interesting for your case as this just pulls in all sentences